# Error during query property from jsonb column with double quotation marks

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, jsonb

I have the PostgreSQL table named 'orders' with the following columns:

```
id | params   (jsonb type)              | valid
1  | {"value": "120", is_active: true}  | true
2  | {"value": "92", is_active: false}  | true
```

I'm trying to perform SELECT query with filter by `params.is_active = true`.
Method which creates filter receives property like

```
filter.property = `(params ->>'is_active')::boolean`
```

The resulting query looks like:

```sql
select * 
from "orders" 
where "valid" = true 
and "(params->>'is_active')::boolean" = true 
limit 50
```

It gives me an error

> ERROR: column "(params->>'is_active')::boolean" does not exist.

When I removed double quotes around jsonb column as:

```sql
select * 
from "orders" 
where "valid" = true 
and (params->>'is_active')::boolean = true 
limit 50
```

it worked fine.

My question: is it possible to provide another (in different format) parameter to filter method instead of

```
(params ->>'is_active')::boolean
```

to avoid such error. I think that I can remove double quotes from resulted query with regex or I can change filter method mechanism to bypass adding quotes but maybe there is an option to just provide another value.

Comment: This clearly looks like a bug in knex.js/node.js

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've tried to execute this query at DBeaver and it gave me the same result.

Comment: Well, the bug/error is to enclose an expression with double quotes.    Double quotes are used for identifiers (column or table names) in SQL, so this makes zero sense. You wouldn't write `where "(price * pieces)" > 100` either, but `where (price * pieces) > 100`

Answer (score 0):

Your jsonb seems wrong.

```
select '{"value": "92", is_active: false}'::jsonb;
```

will fail.

> My question: is it possible to provide another (in different format)
> parameter to filter method instead of

You can use @> and jsonb_path_exists. run following command in DBeaver should be fine. I am not sure nodejs.

```
WITH cte (
    params
) AS (
    SELECT
        '{"value": 120, "is_active": true}'::jsonb
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '{"value": 92, "is_active": false}'::jsonb
)
SELECT
    params,
    params @> '{"is_active": true}'::jsonb,
    jsonb_path_exists(params, '$.is_active ? (@== true)'),
    jsonb_path_exists(params, '$.value ? (@ >= $min)', '{"min":120}')
FROM
    cte;
```